# Location path not routing to where I want to

Tags: angularjs

I am building a web application using Angular JS, but I am failing to make it routing to where I want to.

Basically I have an html page which include multiple pages and I would like to change the page href on click so each of the included pages have their own url.

In my app.js I have built the following routes:

```
    .when('/ContractDetail/:id/?detail', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/ContractDetail.html'
    })
    .when('/ContractDetail/:id/?movements', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/ContractDetail.html'
    })
    .when('/ContractDetail/:id/?historic', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/ContractDetail.html'
    })
    .when('/ContractDetail/:id/?movements', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/ContractDetail.html'
    })
```

And this is my html page with the respective included views:

```
<ul ng-model="selected" ng-change="switchUrl()">

  <li class="detailTitle"><a id="detailContract" ng-click="changeHref('detail')"'>{{appResources.CommonDetailsDetailTabbedTitle}}</a></li>                     
  <li class="movementTitle active"><a id="movContract"  ng-click="changeHref('movements')">{{appResources.CommonDetailsMovementsTabbedTitle}}</a></li>
  <li class="historicTitle"><a id="histContract" ng-click="changeHref('historic')">{{appResources.CommonDetailsHistoricalTabbedTitle}}</a></li>
  <li class="messagesTitle"><a id="msgContract" ng-click="changeHref('messages')">{{appResources.CommonDetailsMessagesTabbedTitle}}</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="detail" class="containerTxt" ng-include="'app/views/includes/ContractDetails.html'"></div>
<div id="movements" class="containerTxt active" ng-include="'app/views/includes/ContractMovements.html'"></div>
<div id="historic" class="containerTxt" ng-include="'app/views/includes/ContractHistoric.html'"></div>
<div id="messages" class="containerTxt" ng-include="'app/views/includes/ContractMessages.html'"></div>
```

The function in controller is doing this:

```
    $scope.changeHref = function (destination) {
        $location.path("#/ContractDetail/" + $routeParams.id + "/" + destination)
    }
```

But the route is not being assumed and I am always getting redirected to the default page: `http://localhost:14959/#`

My goal is everytime I redirect, I take the correct parameter for instance `detail` to show the correct included view in this case, the one with `detail` id.

Comment: Try `"#/ContractDetail/" + $routeParams.id +"/"+ destination`

Comment: @SaiUnique that was indeed wrong, but it was not the problem unfortunately. I have updated that part of the code.

Comment: Why do you have the same url declared four times in your routing?

Comment: Change it to only one     .when('/ContractDetail/:id/?destination', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/ContractDetail.html'
    })   and you can get the value by $routeParams.destination. This will be one of the 4 values you are passing in ng-click

Comment: Or if you want four different routIng change the html files

Comment: @Vivz it also did not work, it went back to the same page

Comment: Any errors i console?. And why are u prefixing the url with # ,maybe try removing it

Comment: @Vivz I already removed it but it did not work, also no console errors

Comment: Change the optional params in your routing. It should be :detail? etc

Comment: @Vivz that solution works. Please answer so I can accept it, and many thanks

Comment: I will. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your config to accommodate all the urls for the `ng-include` and your optional parameters should have proper syntax

```
.when('/ContractDetail/:id/:detail?', {
    templateUrl: 'app/views/ContractDetail.html'
})
.when('/ContractDetail/:id/:movements?', {
    templateUrl: 'app/views/ContractMovements.html'
})
.when('/ContractDetail/:id/:historic?', {
    templateUrl: 'app/views/ContractHistoric.html'
})
.when('/ContractDetail/:id/:movements?', {
    templateUrl: 'app/views/ContractMessages.html'
})
```

Also remove # from the controller's `$location.path`

```
$scope.changeHref = function (destination) {
    $location.path("/ContractDetail/" + $routeParams.id + "/" + destination)
}
```

Comment: actually it was not necessary to add 4 different routes, one was enough :D

Comment: Ok Whatever is requirement :)